# how to edit a div and meta tags in a html page using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file

I have a situation here. I need to edit only meta tags and the contents of a  `<div id="container"></div>` in a remote html page, using php.

The process is, when the user edits the remote html page from edit.php, which loads the remote page's `div#container` (editing is done by html5's content editable attribute) and clicks save button, the edit page sends the html to the server page, say `update_html.php`.

Here in `update_html.php` how can I open `pages/remote_page.html` and write/update only the contents in the `div#container` and the meta tags?

Comment: Try `preg_replace` to reaplce your contents

Comment: What have  you tried so far?

Comment: hi i'm new to php. so far i get the contents using file_get_contents('pages/remote_page.html'). but it loads all the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add some marks in your html file, such as `<!-- container begin -->` and `<!-- container end -->`.

Second, use preg_replace to change them to your content.

e.g.

```
$info = file_get_contents('pages/remote_page.html');
preg_replace('|(<!\-\- container begin \-\->.*<!\-\- container end \-\->)|isU', $_POST['content'], $info);
file_put_contents('pages/remote_page.html', $info);
```

Comment: i tried to replace `file_put_contents('pages/remote_page.html', $info);` with `file_put_contents('pages/remote_page.html', $_POST['content']);` but now it replaces the whole contents in index page.

Comment: hi have found the error :) i didn't leave the spaces between the comment tag and the words. and i also edited your answer. as your code will work only once. thanks :)